# face_encoding function returning an error

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, encoding, face-recognition

I am getting when face_encodings function is being called .

```
TypeError: __call__(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: dlib.fhog_object_detector, image: array, upsample_num_times: int=0) -> dlib.rectangles
Invoked with: <dlib.fhog_object_detector object at 0x7f066f834340>, '36121754-36121734.jpg', 2
```

Here is my code

```
  img = plt.imread(face)
  plt.imshow(img)
  x=face_recognition.load_image_file(face)
  x_code = face_recognition.face_encodings(face)[0]
```

Image path is correct , as I tried outputting the image, it is showing load_image_file() is executing and is returning an array of numbers.

I am not sure where I went wrong.

Chances are the error is likely to be the input type of load_image_file or face_encodings

[face-recognition documentation link](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the parameter variable which i passed to face_encoding()

correct :

```
x=face_recognition.load_image_file(face)
x_code = face_recognition.face_encodings(x)[0]
```

Reason :

According to face-recognition library , load_image_file is like an initial function where we pass the file and store it in a variable (in my case , variable `x`)

Later for any other functions of face_recognition package, We have to pass the variable `x` rather than the file name.

PS : That error details still scares me